# match vector against dataframe with multiple entries in R

Tags: r, merge, match, reshape

I have the following two dataframes:

```
>df1<-data.frame(ID=c(111,222,333,444))
   ID
1 111
2 222
3 333
4 444

>df2<-data.frame(ID=c(111,111,111,222,333,333,444,444,444,444,444,444),CODE=c(1,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5))
    ID CODE
1  111    1
2  111    1
3  111    2
4  222    3
5  333    2
6  333    3
7  444    4
8  444    5
9  444    2
10 444    3
11 444    4
12 444    5
```

and would like to match the ID elements in df1 against the ID elements in df2, to produce a third dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df3<-data.frame(ID=c(111,222,333,444),CODE1=c(1,3,2,4),CODE2=c(1,NA,3,5),CODE3=c(2,NA,NA,2),CODE4=c(NA,NA,NA,3),CODE5=c(NA,NA,NA,4),CODE6=c(NA,NA,NA,5))
   ID CODE1 CODE2 CODE3 CODE4 CODE5 CODE6
1 111     1     1     2    NA    NA    NA
2 222     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 333     2     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 444     4     5     2     3     4     5
```

Note that df2 contains multiple codes for several of the ID elements in df1. I would like df3 to reflect this by including a column for the each of the codes associated with the ID elements.

Thank you in advance for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a "long-to-wide" reshape problem, but you don't have a "time" variable. You can use `ave` plus `seq_along` to create one, like this:

```
df2$TIME <- ave(df2$ID, df2$ID, FUN = seq_along)
df2
#     ID CODE TIME
# 1  111    1    1
# 2  111    1    2
# 3  111    2    3
# 4  222    3    1
# 5  333    2    1
# 6  333    3    2
# 7  444    4    1
# 8  444    5    2
# 9  444    2    3
# 10 444    3    4
# 11 444    4    5
# 12 444    5    6
```

Now, you can easily use either base R's `reshape`....

```
reshape(df2, direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "TIME")
#    ID CODE.1 CODE.2 CODE.3 CODE.4 CODE.5 CODE.6
# 1 111      1      1      2     NA     NA     NA
# 4 222      3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 5 333      2      3     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 7 444      4      5      2      3      4      5
```

... or `dcast` from "reshape2"

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df2, ID ~ TIME, value.var="CODE")
#    ID 1  2  3  4  5  6
# 1 111 1  1  2 NA NA NA
# 2 222 3 NA NA NA NA NA
# 3 333 2  3 NA NA NA NA
# 4 444 4  5  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ddply` function from [`plyr` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) to do the task:

```R
> ddply(df2, .(ID), function (d) { t(d$CODE) })
     ID 1  2  3  4  5  6
  1 111 1  1  2 NA NA NA
  2 222 3 NA NA NA NA NA
  3 333 2  3 NA NA NA NA
  4 444 4  5  2  3  4  5
```

It can be done using `by` to get the rows and then using some clever tricks to make all the rows of the same length before combining them with `rbind`, but using this package would be simpler.